# How to check the exit code of the last command in batch file?

Tags: windows-xp, batch

Inside a batch file on Windows, I use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) like this:

```
...\right_path\7z a output_file_name.zip file_to_be_compressed
```

How could I check the exit code of `7z` and take the appropriate action ?

Comment: Also asked on Stackoverflow: [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/334879/588306)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Test for a return code greater than or equal to 1:

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error
```

or

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 echo Error
```

or test for a return code equal to 0:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo OK
```

You can use other commands such as `GOTO` where I show `echo`.

Comment: I tried your code. I got the following error: `0 was unexpected this time.`

Comment: @Misha: You may have tried it with the percent signs the way I originally posted it. Try it without them or try the other versions I added.

Comment: Found cases where `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 0 even though an error occurred. Happened when checking `%ERRORLEVEL%` in a cmd file. Trying `start /wait` didn't work. The only thing that worked is `if errorlevel 1 (...)`

Comment: Be aware, errorlevel is [not an environment variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx). Here's a good summary of the [pitfalls and subtleties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935693/foolproof-way-to-check-for-nonzero-error-return-code-in-windows-batch-file).

Comment: Might I suggest using `NEQ` instead of `EQU` to support detecting negative return codes? No idea if Windows XP does that, but it’s a thing on modern Windows…

Comment: @binki, negative codes are indicating system errors, not application ones. Which is rarely seen in the wild.

Comment: @AnrDaemon Don’t you want your script to correctly fail in case of a system error instead of silently ignoring it though? I only commented that because I was having trouble with commands failing and not being detected because they were returning negative numbers and hoped that the answer could be fixed to avoid allowing others to fall into the trap of using `GEQ` or `IF ERRORLEVEL` instead of a pattern like `SET ERR=0` `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 SET ERR=1` `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET ERR=1`.

Comment: Depends on the script. Normally, I only handle specific error codes, and just rethrow everything else. This is not the right place to discuss this.

Comment: I disagree, it's the perfect place. The question is how to check the exit code of the last command. if the exit code is -1 then we should know about it. Regardless of whether that is an application error code or a system error code, it's still an error code and it should be trapped and handled. I want to know about all errors, so NEQ 0 wins for me every time over GEQ 1...

Comment: I've changed my answer to use `NEQ 0`.

Answer (score 13):

This really works when you have: App1.exe calls -> .bat which runs -->  app2.exe

App2 returns errorlevel 1... but you need to catch that in the .bat and re-raise it to app1... otherwise .bat eats the errorlevel and app1 never knows.

Method:

In .bat:

```
app2.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 EXIT /B 1
```

This is a check after app2 for errorlevel. If > 0, then the .bat exits and sets errorlevel to 1 for the calling app1.

Comment: it could be even better if you returned the same error back to app1. i didn't try this out, but it should work :  `if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%`.

Comment: At least in Windows, %ERRORLEVEL% can be a negative number (e.g. I have a program that returns -1 on errors). `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%` might be a better option. But you really need to know what the program returns on errors. Some programs return certain non-zero codes for special types of success.

Comment: If app2 is the last thing you run in the bat file, the error code will propagate.

Answer (score 4):

I had a batch script in Teamcity pipeline and it did not exit after it's child script did exit with code 1.

To fix the problem I added this string `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT 1` after the child script call.

**main-script.bat**

```
...some code
call child-script.bat
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT 1
...some code
```

After the child script call exit result is saved to `%ERRORLEVEL%`. If it did exit with an error `%ERRORLEVEL%` would not be equal to 0 and in this case we exit with code 1 (error).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```all-bat
cd.>nul | call Your_7z_File.Bat && Goto :Next || Goto :Error

:: Or...

cd.>nul | ...\right_path\7z.exe a output_file_name.zip file_to_be_compressed && Goto :Next || Goto :Error
```

1) Set errorlevel == `0`

```all-bat
cd.>nul
```

2) Redirect by `|` to simultaneously call `Your_7z_File.Bat`

```all-bat
cd.>nul | call Your_7z_File.Bat
```

3) Lets the output/errorlevel to a conditional execution `&&` and `||` filter the next action

```all-bat
cd.>nul | call Your_7z_File.Bat && Goto :Next || Goto :Error
```

You can also test it in command line adding `echo/`:

```all-bat
cd.>nul | call Your_7z_File.Bat && echo\Goto :Next || echo\Goto :Error
```

- **[Conditional Execution || && | & operators...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[What is the easiest way to reset ERRORLEVEL to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45255111/8177207)**