# CMD - Successful or not indication?

Tags: windows, command-line

Suppose I have some commands in a bat file :

```
echo 1
copy existingFile1 c:
echo 2
copy existingFile1 notExistingDrive:
echo 3
attrib -r attrib notExistingFile
```

Those are just demos of commands that contains successful commands and also  "*not-ran-to-completion*" return codes.

Visualization :

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way I can get an indication that at least one operation has *not-ran-to-completion* ?

psuedo :

```
do something1
do something2
do something3
if noErrorsAll(something1,something2,something3)
 do something4
```

NB I prefer not to check everytime "if exists".There can be other halts than "not-exists"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check the exit code of the last command in batch file?](http://superuser.com/questions/194662/how-to-check-the-exit-code-of-the-last-command-in-batch-file)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No. it's not a dup. [see this image](http://i.imgur.com/m3iCEzW.png) as you can see - it didnt find the file and yet - errorlevel is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect/Append the STDERR from each command to (e.g.) `log.txt`, then read the contents or size into a variable and test for empty/zero bytes.